# MySQL Group By weeks

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-by

Есть таблица клиентов, где указана дата регистрации в системе. Необходимо вытащить статистику по регистрации понедельно за каждый месяц, с группировкой по company_id. ВАЖНО, чтобы недели считались по числам 01-10, 11-17, 18- 24, 25-31. В колонках должен быть count() и GROUP_CONCAT(clients.id).

Пробовал так:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7df063/10

Проблема в том, что WEEK это номер недели, числа он в расчет не берет.
В идеале на выходе должно получиться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ВАЖНО, чтобы недели считались по числам 01-10, 11-17, 18- 24, 25-31

```
SELECT
  company_id,
  YEAR(dt) AS `year`,
  MONTH(dt) AS `month`,
CASE WHEN DAY(dt) < 11 THEN 1
     WHEN DAY(dt) < 18 THEN 2
     WHEN DAY(dt) < 25 THEN 3
                       ELSE 4 END AS `week_number`, 
  count(id) AS `cnt`, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) AS `client_list`
FROM clients 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a9b4cfafab49baac80ac0a1787318d9)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, то что нужно! 
Еще момент, в таблице клиентов есть поле budget - деньги которые он оставил в компании. Необходимы вытащить IFNULL(SUM(budget), 0) AS `budget`. Но ругается: 1056. Can't group on 'budget'

Comment: @YevgeniyM Дайте, догадаюсь - Вы это влепили где-то в начале... а надо где-то после CASE. Или надо изменить номера полей в выражениях группировки и сортировки.